# Accessing Wildfly AS remotely using jconsole from a windows machine

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jconsole

I Have Wildfly running on a Linux machine I'm trying to access it from a windows machine on the same network using `jconsole` without success.

I can access the managment console of the wildlfy instance from the browser using:

```
http://192.168.1.6:9990/
```

I've read that I have to add the `jboss-client.jar` to the jconsole class path, but I cant seem to get it to work, this is my attempt

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\jconsole.jar:C:\Progra~1\Java\wildfly\jboss-client.jar
```

I'm running the command from Powershell I have my environment PATH set so I can use jconsole no problem, so I think my syntax is the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$WILDFLY_HOME\bin` there are [jconsole-scripts](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JMX+subsystem+configuration): `jconsole.(sh|bat|ps1)`  which set up the class path for you, so setting it up manually should not be necessary. If you really need to do that, analyzing the scripts will probably help to how to escape it correctly.

Also, on [Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) the classpath entries are separated with a semicolon `;` but on [Unix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html) it is a colon `:`